# What files are in the project root directory after branching?

Tags: xcode, git

When using a local repository with Xcode, I'm wondering what versions of files are actually the files you see in the project directory on the hard drive, if these files are involved in multiple branches.

Since the contents of files can be different in different branches, or even when saved vs not yet committed, then I assume a lot of this stuff is saved only in the .git folder. But at what point do the actual files themselves change during the process of using git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> at what point do the actual files themselves change during the process of using git

At a [`git checkout aBranch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) (called ["Switch Branch" in XCode](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/02/29/git-branch-management-with-xcode.html)): if a file content is different from the current branch, the file will change then.